# How to make custom shape AppBar and set it default with flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to build an custom shaped appbar and I have but I don't want to set same appbar to every page. I have custom themes and previous projects I was managing my appbar themes from here but in this case I cannot set appbar theme because of custom shape.

Is there better way to set custom appbar or do I have to create custom widget (appbar) and set for every page manually?

This is my custom appbar

[image: my custom appbar]

This was my appbar theme and I cannot implement custom appbar to here

```
 ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      elevation: 0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      foregroundColor: Color(0xff432fbf),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `PreferredSizeWidget` and have the theme on MaterialApp or can be overridden Theme on this widget

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); //your widgets. 
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(yourAppBarHeight);
}
```

Comment: and use like  `appBar:MyAppBar()`

Comment: this is what i am using right now i think this is the best practice

Comment: for sharing, I think so